# Bootstrap alert disapperas after a few seconds

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, handler, ierrorhandler

I try to create a simple form with Bootstrap and with error handling.
I create a form and after the submit clicking the error should appear, but the error only appears for a few seconds ...

Here the code:

http://codebin.org/view/8e8b46ae

Thanks :)

Comment: Please paste the _relevant_ code bits into the question using the code formatting. Don't expect helping hands to follow your links but instead make it easy for them to see and understand the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the warning, you have to suppress the original form submit behavior by returning `false`, otherwise the browser processes the form submit.

```
if(name.val() == ''){
    ...
   return false;
}
```